# why isn't this working? jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, settimeout

It's supposed to toggle between the functions when '#drop a' is clicked. What's the deal?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#drop a').toggle(function() {
        $('body').animate({'margin-top': '300px'}, 600);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#drop a').css('background-position', '-40px 0px');
        }, 1000);
    }, function() {
        $('body').animate('margin-top': '80px'}, 600);
    });
});
```

Comment: `.toggle()` used in that manner is deprecated. Also, choose a descriptive title for your question.

Comment: @ahren What would you suggest then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that you forgot the starting bracket:

```
// ---------------v
$('body').animate({'margin-top': '80px'}, 600);
```

which should definitely cause the fatal error.